# Export ESX Thin Partition VM

Tags: virtual-machine, storage, vsphere, esxi

I have a question. I need to export a VM set up to Thin Partition. But the problem is that this VM is too big ... Regarding to VSPHERE client, it says that this VM is about 2TO used. But someone told me that when you have a VM set up to Thin Partition, when you’ll export it, the size will not be what you see on vsphere client , it will be a lot smaller.

Is that true ?

PS : Sorry my English if my English is a little bad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. When a VM is exported as an OVF from the vSphere Client, it will only export the data actually being stored. This means the disk will not be of the same size as it is on the VMFS/NFS storage.